# Raspberry pi serial communication-python write command issue

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi

I use PC to control extral device, and this device is serial port communicate with PC, and it works good. I can send the commands to device from PC to device. The belwo is command structure.Python versio is 2.7.

```
Initialize=[0xEE,0x01,0x01] 
ser.write(Initialize)
```

Now, I use the raspberry pi to connect this device, and I'm sure rapsberry pi has connected with thid device. I use the below command to test connection.

```
ser=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", baudrate=115200, timeout=0.5)
print ("Port "+ ser.portstr + "opened:" + str(ser.isOpen()))
```

Now, the issue is I cannot write the data to device as I did in PC. The python version is 3.4.2.
Write command:

```
Initialize=[0xEE,0x01,0x01] 
ser.write(Initialize)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/ssbar/ss.py", line 65, in <module>
    ser.write(Initialize)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 475, in write
    n = os.write(self.fd, d)
TypeError: 'list' does not support the buffer interface
```

Is anyone knows how to fix it? Many thank for your help!

Comment: The type you are looking for is wrong.https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html

Comment: In Python 3 I think you will have to convert your list Initialize into a byte stream.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer. It works now. The belwo is correct command.

```
x=bytearray(Initialize)
ser.write(x)
```